# VS Code autocompletion base on word in file

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I just begin with VS Code and I'm really happy with it at the moment !

I'm coming from Notepad++ and I didn't found any IDE at the same "level" of it for the things I'm doing.. Until now! I really like what VS Code is doing and how all modern integrated technology is helping me.

But I miss one thing that NPP do is the autocomplete base on word in the file. So can I do the same in VS Code ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could be tough if there's no support for it in the IDE since VSCode doesn't support plugins yet. You might want to go with something higher powered like Visual Studio Community.

Comment: I'm good with VS Code.. I dont want a project manager just a code editor like NPP with more useful functionality. But if I can't do it.. It's okay.. I can live w/o. I hope they implement it in future !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793337/vscode-intellisense-autocomplete-for-javascript - Seems this is only available for JavaScript at this time.

Comment: Maybe i do it wrong, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Just took the VS Code survey... Exactly what I mentioned in the feedback, plus Ctrl + D to duplicate current line to the line below... Speeds up coding like crazy!

Comment: Just found this... for the duplicate line function: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings

Comment: I have posted a solution that works on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639995/1713103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your settings.json, and restart vs code:

```
// Controls how JavaScript IntelliSense works.

// Always include all words from the current document.
"javascript.suggest.alwaysAllWords": true,

// Complete functions with their parameter signature.
"javascript.suggest.useCodeSnippetsOnMethodSuggest": true
```

Comment: can confirm, mac os sierra vs code 1.21.1, adding these to my user settings json gives them a green underline, on hover it says "Unknown configuration setting"

The only other auto complete support I can find is this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atishay-Jain.All-Autocomplete
And the "Spaces inside braces" extension. The "indentED" extension might be good.

Comment: searching "vs code javascript autocomplete braces" gives some interesting results..

Comment: Highly recommend this matching bracket pair colorizer  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer

Comment: Looks like these new settings are on by default :
```
  // Controls if the editor should automatically close brackets after opening them
  "editor.autoClosingBrackets": true,

  // Controls if the editor should automatically adjust the indentation when users type, paste or move lines. Indentation rules of the language must be available.
  "editor.autoIndent": true,
``` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 10):

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
      },
```

Comment: This solves why word completion was not working inside strings in ruby files.

Comment: This solved my autocomplete issues with JavaScript too! I was getting sick of having to copy/paste or re-type my strings.

Answer (score -1):

For autocomplete brackets use this setting:

```
// Complete functions with their parameter signature.
"javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true
```

Comment: You've missed understand the question. He needs to autocomplete words that are in the file, not the function signatures