# Visual Studio Code autocomplete for words in same file

Tags: macos, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

[Note: I've already tried `javascript.suggest.alwaysAllWords` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793337/vscode-intellisense-autocomplete-for-javascript), but the suggested settings just give me `Unknown configuration setting` in Code 1.8.1 for macOS.]

---

Autocomplete works fine for me in Visual Studio Code, but only for code in outside modules. That's great for what it's worth, but I'm really missing the buffer-based autocomplete from Sublime which essentially includes any word in a currently-open buffer as an autocomplete option.

For example, when I type this:

```
hashToPage : String -> Page
hashT
```

I want autocomplete to offer up `oPage` as a completion for `hashT`. Instead, I have to retype the entire string.

**Is there a way to tweak the settings to include words from the current page?**

(Or all open buffers, or any approach that indexes variable and function names that I've created?)

Comment: See comment below.

Answer (score 6):

Searching the internet I found the following option:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": false,
  "strings": false
},
```

Fix like this and that worked for me correctly:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": true,
  "strings": true
},
```

Comment: Still not working, though perhaps I'm Doing It Wrong™. Presumably "editor.quickSuggestions" is a key added to settings.json (aka USER SETTINGS)?

Comment: Yes, it is in the last version in the configuration

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong, then. Strings I type in one open file are still not auto-completing in another open file.

Comment: Your question title should be changed if you are also looking for word completion from other opened files.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5312#issuecomment-724717894 This is being added soon to vscode.  I assume you have the `Editor: Word Based Suggestions` enabled (that is the default)?