# Visual Studio Code enable suggestion code JavaScript like in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I am looking for a solution how can I enable all suggestions for JavaScript code, for example I write this same code in VSC and WebStorm:

[image]

In WebStorm I have all suggestion that match the word `remov`, but in VSC I have information: `No suggestions.`

I try use answer from this question, but nothing work:

[How to enable Intellisense for JavaScript in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055382/how-to-enable-intellisense-for-javascript-in-visual-studio-code)

[VSCode intelliSense autocomplete for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793337/vscode-intellisense-autocomplete-for-javascript)

[VS Code autocompletion base on word in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283811/vs-code-autocompletion-base-on-word-in-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have version VSC 1.24.0

My settings.json file:

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\php7\\php.exe",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "files.associations": {
        "*.ejs": "html",
        "*.js": "javascript"
    },
    "css.fileExtensions": [
        "css",
        "scss"
    ],
    "sublimeTextKeymap.promptV3Features": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Afterglow",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
    },
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true,
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
    "editor.parameterHints": true
}
```

*Edit:*

All code which I use:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {


    function Calendar(input) {
        this.now = new Date();
        this.day = this.now.getDate();
        this.month = this.now.getMonth();
        this.year = this.now.getFullYear();

        this.input = input; 
        this.divCnt = null; 
        this.divHeader = null; 
        this.divTable = null; 
        this.divDateText = null; 
        this.divButtons = null; 


        this.init = function() {

            this.divCnt = document.createElement('div');
            this.divCnt.classList.add('calendar');

            this.divButtons = document.createElement('div');
            this.divButtons.className = "calendar-prev-next";

            this.divDateText = document.createElement('div');
            this.divDateText.className = 'date-name';

            this.divHeader = document.createElement('div');
            this.divHeader.classList.add('calendar-header');

            this.divHeader.appendChild(this.divButtons);
            this.divHeader.appendChild(this.divDateText);

            this.divHeader.appendChild();
        };

    }

});
```

Comment: You need to provide a more complete code example that shows how `divHeader` is declared and assigned

Comment: This is not about the `divHeader` declaration. I just gave a brief example. I just want to force a syntax suggestion like the webstorm does.

Comment: I need more context because that context is what determines why intellisense is not be showing here. Please provide a complete code example

Comment: @MattBierner i edit my post. And I check Sublime Text 3, in this program suggestions appear correctly as in WebStom. Only in VSC suggestions do not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code's intellisense cannot infer the type of `divCnt` since it is not assigned in the constructor. You can enable proper intellisense by either assigning the value in the constructor or by using jsdocs:

```
function Calendar(input) {
    this.divCnt = /** @type {HTMLDivElement} */ (null);
}
```

Root cause is https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10868

Answer (score -1):

Just install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en) and [@types/jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery?activeTab=readme), then restart your PC.