# how to fix node code autocompletion aren't enabled in vscode ( with npmjs installed )

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm facing an issue with VScode and NodeJS with the code autocompletion

I did a bit of reserch on this topic and i found this
[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777494/how-to-enable-node-js-code-autocompletion-in-vscode), I'm facing the similar issue mentioned in that post.

when I type `console` or any vanilla JavaScript code, VScode detect it and try's to suggest an autocomplete code.

but when I write NodeJS server side JavaScript code VScode aren't detecting it.

I've tried the solutions for that post, and here the output.

`npm` is installed globally

`VScode --version` 1.64.0

`NodeJS --version` 14.16.0

`V8 -v` 9.1.269.39

`OS` Windows 10

**1 -** run `npm init` to create package.json.
It  creates package.json but VScode didn't recognize it as a node code.

**2 - run** `npm install --save-dev @types/node`.
Yes this works but I don't want to run this command and install mode_modules on every project, even if the project doesn't require any npm packages.

So simply my question is:

How can I install the code autocompletion globally on my system, without needing to install @types/node every time ?

Comment: You can install a node package globally by adding `-g` to the install command. Whether this solves the issue, I don't know.

Comment: Also your version of nodeJs is a year old. You might consider downloading a new version.